nginx php-fpm redis configuration "socket error on read socket"
my  localhost is on ubuntu with nginx + php-fpm 8.1
server {
    server_name "~^({[a-z]}2\.)*(?<project>\w+)\.(.*)localhost$";
    root /home/fw/public_html;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

I'm running redis-stack in a docker
docker run -d --name redis-stack -p 6379:6379 -p 8001:8001 -v /home/fw/redis/data:/data -v /home/fw/redis/redis.conf:/redis-stack.conf redis/redis-stack:latest

# in redis.conf
unixsocket /run/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 770

# Server
redis_version:7.2.4
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:3a23a5ac67fe7008
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 6.5.0-27-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
monotonic_clock:POSIX clock_gettime
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:c11-builtin
gcc_version:11.4.0
process_id:9
process_supervised:no
run_id:ac8418a9548435ac2a3cad2c5d483b7e578e1420
tcp_port:6379
server_time_usec:1713180070510705
uptime_in_seconds:1238
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:1904038
executable:/opt/redis-stack/bin/redis-server
config_file:/redis-stack.conf
io_threads_active:0
listener0:name=tcp,bind=127.0.0.1,port=6379
listener1:name=unix,bind=/run/redis.sock

# Clients
connected_clients:3
cluster_connections:0
maxclients:10000
client_recent_max_input_buffer:8
client_recent_max_output_buffer:0
blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0
total_blocking_keys:0
total_blocking_keys_on_nokey:0

blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0
total_blocking_keys:0
total_blocking_keys_on_nokey:0

# Memory
used_memory:1372880
used_memory_human:1.31M
used_memory_rss:22020096
used_memory_rss_human:21.00M
used_memory_peak:1426480
used_memory_peak_human:1.36M
used_memory_peak_perc:96.24%
used_memory_overhead:1200296
used_memory_startup:1194056
used_memory_dataset:172584
used_memory_dataset_perc:96.51%
allocator_allocated:1485408
allocator_active:8323072
allocator_resident:10420224
total_system_memory:15646117888
total_system_memory_human:14.57G
used_memory_lua:31744
used_memory_vm_eval:31744
used_memory_lua_human:31.00K
used_memory_scripts_eval:0
number_of_cached_scripts:0
number_of_functions:0
number_of_libraries:0
used_memory_vm_functions:32768
used_memory_vm_total:64512
used_memory_vm_total_human:63.00K
used_memory_functions:184
used_memory_scripts:184
used_memory_scripts_human:184B
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:5.60
allocator_frag_bytes:6837664
allocator_rss_ratio:1.25
allocator_rss_bytes:2097152
rss_overhead_ratio:2.11
rss_overhead_bytes:11599872
mem_fragmentation_ratio:16.30
mem_fragmentation_bytes:20669512
mem_not_counted_for_evict:8
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_total_replication_buffers:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:5784
mem_cluster_links:0
mem_aof_buffer:8
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.3.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
lazyfreed_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
async_loading:0
current_cow_peak:0
current_cow_size:0
current_cow_size_age:0
current_fork_perc:0.00
current_save_keys_processed:0
current_save_keys_total:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1713178893
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:0
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_saves:1
rdb_last_cow_size:282624
rdb_last_load_keys_expired:0
rdb_last_load_keys_loaded:0
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_rewrites:0
aof_rewrites_consecutive_failures:0
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0
aof_current_size:483
aof_base_size:131
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:0

total_connections_received:4
total_commands_processed:260
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_net_input_bytes:4569
total_net_output_bytes:1237771
total_net_repl_input_bytes:0
total_net_repl_output_bytes:0
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_input_repl_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_output_repl_kbps:0.00
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:27
evicted_keys:0
evicted_clients:0
total_eviction_exceeded_time:0
current_eviction_exceeded_time:0
keyspace_hits:22
keyspace_misses:0
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
pubsubshard_channels:0
latest_fork_usec:816
total_forks:1
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
total_active_defrag_time:0
current_active_defrag_time:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_error_replies:0
dump_payload_sanitizations:0
total_reads_processed:234
total_writes_processed:232
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0
reply_buffer_shrinks:201
reply_buffer_expands:198
eventloop_cycles:12579
eventloop_duration_sum:2400062
eventloop_duration_cmd_sum:28832
instantaneous_eventloop_cycles_per_sec:9
instantaneous_eventloop_duration_usec:267
acl_access_denied_auth:0
acl_access_denied_cmd:0
acl_access_denied_key:0
acl_access_denied_channel:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_failover_state:no-failover
master_replid:1363e4c8fc50c52fcb9833536e1a66fcc7ddfcfa
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:0
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:1.362032
used_cpu_user:1.445511
used_cpu_sys_children:0.000000
used_cpu_user_children:0.005820
used_cpu_sys_main_thread:1.360941
used_cpu_user_main_thread:1.445472

# Modules
module:name=timeseries,ver=11012,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]
module:name=RedisCompat,ver=1,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]
module:name=search,ver=20813,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[ReJSON],options=[handle-io-errors]
module:name=ReJSON,ver=20610,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[search],using=[],options=[handle-io-errors]
module:name=bf,ver=20612,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]
module:name=redisgears_2,ver=20020,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]

# Errorstats

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=5,expires=0,avg_ttl=0

I've installed phpredis (with pecl)
$ php -i 

Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 6.0.2
Redis Sentinel Version => 1.0
Available serializers => php, json
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
redis.arrays.algorithm => no value => no value
redis.arrays.auth => no value => no value
redis.arrays.autorehash => 0 => 0
redis.arrays.connecttimeout => 0 => 0
redis.arrays.consistent => 0 => 0
redis.arrays.distributor => no value => no value
redis.arrays.functions => no value => no value
redis.arrays.hosts => no value => no value
redis.arrays.index => 0 => 0
redis.arrays.lazyconnect => 0 => 0
redis.arrays.names => no value => no value
redis.arrays.pconnect => 0 => 0
redis.arrays.previous => no value => no value
redis.arrays.readtimeout => 0 => 0
redis.arrays.retryinterval => 0 => 0
redis.clusters.auth => no value => no value
redis.clusters.cache_slots => 0 => 0
redis.clusters.persistent => 0 => 0
redis.clusters.read_timeout => 0 => 0
redis.clusters.seeds => no value => no value
redis.clusters.timeout => 0 => 0
redis.pconnect.connection_limit => 0 => 0
redis.pconnect.echo_check_liveness => 1 => 1
redis.pconnect.pool_detect_dirty => 0 => 0
redis.pconnect.pool_pattern => no value => no value
redis.pconnect.pool_poll_timeout => 0 => 0
redis.pconnect.pooling_enabled => 1 => 1
redis.session.early_refresh => 0 => 0
redis.session.lock_expire => 0 => 0
redis.session.lock_retries => 100 => 100
redis.session.lock_wait_time => 20000 => 20000
redis.session.locking_enabled => 0 => 0

Now running a php script, I can connect but can't work with the connection :
$redis = new Redis(); 

try {
    $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); // => true (it is connecting to redis ?)
   // $redis->auth('');  // => string(42) "read error on connection to 127.0.0.1:6379" 

   // $pong = $redis->ping();             //  => string(27) "socket error on read socket" 
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage())  ;       
    die;
}

socket configuration somewhere ? persistence of the connection ?
(thanks for help)

ok solved, thanks to Michael Grunder that maintains phpredis (https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis)
the redis.conf file specified had bind directive that didn't allow access from outside the container
adding bind * -::* to redis.conf fixes it (although it doesnt sound super secure & I assume it'd be better to point precisely to each interface allowed).
